# C# UDP Socket.ReceiveFrom() breaks loop without exeption

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to make a game using sockets and UDP, i made a server class where when i call the start method i run a task with a loop to receive packets and process them, i used `Socket.ReceiveFrom(packet, ref sender);` inside a try catch block with everything inside a while loop, first i forgot to add `Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 25000));` so i got a loop of bind exeptions which is normal but now that i added this line my program is freaking out see the code bellow

```
    public class UDPServer
    {
        public UDPServer()
        {
            Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork ,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
            Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 25000));
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            IsBound = true;

            try
            {
                Task.Run(NetworkLoop);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        private void NetworkLoop()
        {
            EndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            byte[] packet = new byte[1];
            int dataSize = 0;

            while (IsBound)
            {
                try
                {
                    dataSize = Socket.ReceiveFrom(packet, ref sender);
                    Console.WriteLine(sender.ToString() + " with " + packet.Length + " of " + dataSize);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reading exeption : " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I debugged this and it seems that now when going step by step to the line 
`dataSize = Socket.ReceiveFrom(packet, ref sender);` it just both exit the try catch block without any exeption catched AND breaks the while loop...

Is this normal behaviour ??

Comment: Why such a low buffer size? => `byte[] packet = new byte[1];`

Comment: I'm new to this i just wanted to test reception before actually processing packets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UDPServer.Start()` method is not blocking, because `Task.Run` will run asynchronously.

```cs
Task.Run(NetworkLoop); // This is non-blocking
```

Your UDP server will work by either:

```
Task.Run(NetworkLoop).Wait(); // This is blocking
```

or

```cs
new UDPServer().Start();

Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> key to stop UDP server...");
Console.ReadLine(); // This block until user hit <enter> key
```

Comment: Ok i just didn't understood how .ReceiveFrom() worked and the concept of "Blocking" in debug mode it felt that the debugger just bailed but it is normal behaviour, it just waits for a packet and return once it gets one, thanks for the answere